# Authenticate using Microsoft Oauth2 against custom application and Cookie/Token info

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0

Here is my scenario - I have a simple Web App that was uses Microsoft Entra Authentication. When I visit the website in a browser and put in a Username and password and authenticate, I get a number of items that I want to extract - in particular the AppServiceAuthSession Cookie and a Bearer Token.

See below for the standard MS login page:

[image]

What I would like to do is using something like postman be able to call an API, pass it the username and password and get above items. Unfortunately I am an over-enthusiastic amateur when it comes to APIs, Auth etc.

And I suspect I have missed a couple of key steps.

Answer (score 0):

> **I would like to do is using something like postman be able to call an API, pass it the username and password and get above items.**

Based on your requirement you can make use of ROPC flow to call an API.

- ROPC flow is not recommended by Micrsoft for security purpose.
- Personal Microsoft account and accounts enabled MFA are not supported in this flow.
- Hence, you need to make use of other interactive flow such as Authorization code flow where the user gets redirected to the browser to login.

If you want to **call an API by passing username and password**, then check the below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access openid
username:User@XXX.onmicrosoft.com
password:UserPassword
grant_type:password
client_secret:Clientsecret
```

***The tokens will be generated:***

[image]

For ***sample***, using the above generated access token you can call the Microsoft Graph API:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

[image]

***You can pass the scope for your custom API and call the API using the access token.***

If you do not want to pass **`client_secret`**, then enable public client flows like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth-ropc)

Comment: Unfortunately I had already tried that, but I only get bad request :(

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot?

Comment: I did manage to get the above working - which did give me a Bearer token, however, I am not getting the AppServiceAuthSession cookie that I need

Comment: What details you need exactly?

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1148193/how-to-get-appserviceauthsession-cookie-using-acce

Comment: If you are generating via Postman you will get only tokens only AppServiceAuthSession cookie

Comment: I feel I am getting closer - I think my issue is the Scope in the above is for graph.microsoft - which doesn't match my app (obviously) - so when I call https://app.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login - it gives me a 401.

Comment: You shouldn't pass graph scope. You need to grant Api permission for the custom api and pass the scope as api://**/.default